# Xamarin Forms Pop-in with custom renderers

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms app for android that makes use of custom renderers for images. I have optimized these images to the point where the Bitmaps are only around 600kb in memory with `InSampleSize`, but I am having issues with pop-in. Namely, when I open a page using these images from my `MasterDetailPage`, the images load fast, but you can still see them pop into view 100-200ms after the page is displayed.

Here's how I'm loading the pages in my `MasterDetailPage`

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var temp = new NavigationPage(new Pages.HomePage());
    Detail = temp;
    IsPresented = false;
}
```

What I would like to do is, if possible, pre-render the page before it is navigated to in the UI to cover up the pop-in, or any other solution that would essentially remove it completely.

Answer (score 1):

Usually in Xamarin Forms people use [FFImageLoading](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading) library

- Xamarin.iOS, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.Forms and Windows (WinRT, UWP)
  support
- Configurable disk and memory caching
- Multiple image views using the same image source (url, path, resource) will use only one bitmap which is cached in memory (less memory usage)
- Deduplication of similar download/load requests. (If 100 similar requests arrive at same time then one real loading will be performed while 99 others
  will wait)
- Error and loading placeholders support
- Images can be automatically downsampled to specified size (less memory usage)
- Fluent API which is inspired by Picasso naming SVG & WebP support
- Image loading Fade-In animations support
- Can retry image downloads (RetryCount, RetryDelay)
- Android bitmap optimization. Saves 50% of memory by trying not to use transparency channel when possible.
- Transformations support BlurredTransformation CircleTransformation,
  RoundedTransformation, CornersTransformation, CropTransformation
  ColorSpaceTransformation, GrayscaleTransformation,
  SepiaTransformation, TintTransformation FlipTransformation,
  RotateTransformation
- Supports custom transformations (native platform
  ITransformation implementations)

[Here](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/wiki) you can find some docs

Answer (score 0):

First, add that image in the following path, here I have taken 'Ex' as project name -

> Ex/Ex/Ex.Android/Resources/drawable/

If the drawable folder doesn't exist then create it.
Then open visual studio, in the solution explorer find for the drawable folder. Then right-click it and click on add existing item and add all the images you placed in the drawable folder.

Then you can use the image on every page, i.e. -
`<Image Source="ImageName.png" />`

You can even use this in your pop-up.